# Is there a way to run a firebase function on a given date & time once?

Tags: reactjs, function, firebase

I am working on a eCommerce PWA using react & firebase. I want to clear the cart if the user didn't finish the purchase in 3 minutes after they add the first product to their cart. How can I achive that using react, firebase and cloud functions?

I've tried node cron but the function finished with status: 'timeout' then started again and so on.

Comment: If you tried something that you think should work, but you couldn't get it to work, share the [minimal, complete code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

use Api providers like

https://timezonedb.com/api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

refer

https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api

or

use a timeout function with javascript native Date method

Comment: Please provide an answer to the question rather than a link to an answer to the question. See [the tag info for the `link-only-answers` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) on [meta.so].